# Create a presence/absence matrix from two variables of a dataframe but adding the information of one third variable from the df instead of value 1

Tags: r, matrix

I would like how to convert the information of a dataframe into a presence/absence matrix according the relation between two variables, but adding the information of one third variable from the dataframe instead of 1.

For example, if I have the dabase `mydf`, which has the weight and length of some individuals trapped in two different days; I would like to get the matrices `weight`and `length` , where the rows are the days, the columns the individuals and within the matrix is the data of the variables selected (here `weight` and `length` are not matrices for explaining briefly the question).

```
mydf <- read.table(text="day - individual - weight - length
1 - 1 - 20 - 12
1 - 2 - 18 - 23
1 - 3 - 36 - 26
1 - 4 - 36 - 15
1 - 5 - 41 - 56
2 - 1 - 25 - 16
2 - 3 - 40 - 30
2 - 5 - 46 - 60
2 - 6 - 30 - 30
2 - 7 - 12 - 35", 
                   sep="-", header=TRUE)
mydf
```

**weight**

```
  day ind_1 ind_2 ind_3 ind_4 ind_5  ind_6  ind_7
1   1    20   18     36   36     41     NA     NA
2   2    25   NA     40   NA     46     30     12
```

**length**

```
  day ind_1 ind_2 ind_3 ind_4 ind_5 ind_6 ind_7
1   1    12   23     26   15     56   NA     NA
2   2    16   NA     30   NA     60   30     35
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `dcast` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(mydf, day~paste0('ind_', individual),
                   value.var='weight', sum, fill=NA_real_)
#  day ind_1 ind_2 ind_3 ind_4 ind_5 ind_6 ind_7
#1   1    20    18    36    36    41    NA    NA
#2   2    25    NA    40    NA    46    30    12
```

and for 'length'

```
dcast(mydf, day~paste0('ind_', individual),
                      value.var='length', sum, fill=NA_integer_)
#  day ind_1 ind_2 ind_3 ind_4 ind_5 ind_6 ind_7
#1   1    12    23    26    15    56    NA    NA
#2   2    16    NA    30    NA    60    30    35
```

Or using `base R`

```
xtabs(weight~day+individual, mydf)
```

Comment: It's perfect and very simply. 
Out of curiosity, I have tried to use it to get a presence/absence matrix between `days~individuals` puting individual as `value.var` and removing the sum but it doesn't work. 
Can `dcast' do it or it is other function?

Comment: @Ruben I think you need `length` instead of `sum` in the fun.aggregate i..e `dcast(mydf, day~paste0('ind_', individual),value.var='weight', length)` and if there are duplicate elements, then create function like `function(x) if(length(x)>1) 1 0`

Comment: To be a bit more accurate for duplicate elements  `dcast(mydf, day~paste0('ind_', individual),value.var='weight', function(x) if(length(x)>=1) 1 else 0 )`